# quadrotor accelerometer unstable

Tags: accelerometer, robotics, kalman-filter

I am currently working on my project quadrotor. I am using ADXL335 accelerometer and L3G4200D gyroscope interfaced with an atemga 128. When I check reading from accelerometer without running motors, values are accurate and stable. But when I start motors, values start to fluctuate. The more I increase the speed the more they fluctuate. I tried Kalman filter, the results seem same just less fluctuating but still not enough for a stable flight. My gyroscope readings also give too much drift. Is this suppose to happen or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electrical engineering.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to help you as "fluctuations" can be caused by several things.

Just checked out the datasheet of the ADXL335 accelerometer. Have you added the bandwidth limiting capasitors on the output Cx,Cy and CZ. If not, they might help you in reducing the fluctuations.

Another thing that might cause your fluctuations interference from the motor cables to the signal cables.
If you havent used screened/shielded cables for the accelerometer change them and make sure that you try to reduce whatever interference you might find.
You might find some hints for how to do good emc design [Here](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/circuits/emc-emi/design-techniques-for-emc.php)

Answer (score 0):

From your statement, I would assume that the motors would be causing the interference. The way I see it, it could be caused one of two ways:

1. The PCB was custom designed, houses both power electronics and the sensitive measurement units and not enough care was taken to isolate the sensitive parts from the interference generated on the board.
2. The magnetic field from the motors are causing the fluctuations. This could be because the IMU is too close to the motors, improperly isolated or improperly positionned. Try avoiding installing the IMU on the same plane as the motors. We currently have our **IMU placed about 20 cm above the center of gravity** of our drone. I cannot confirm that it caused the accelerometer to fluctuate, but it did have enormous influences on the compass when it was placed only 10 cm above the center of gravity.